# get json from controller MVC in java script

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make some mvc application and I have a problem. I want to get json from mvc controller in javascript file:

JS:

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetJsonTest", "JsonTest")';
$.getJSON(actionUrl, function (response) {
    if (response != null) {
        var html = "<li>" + response.Id + " " + response.Name + " " + response.Author + "</li>";
        $("h2").append(html);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetJsonTest() {
    var books = new Book() {
        Id = '1',
        Name = "1+1",
        Author = "Varnava",
        Price = 100
    };
    return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It's not working. I have 404 error. It cant get something from controller. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for bad English. Hope you understand what I ask.

Comment: What's the name of the Controller? From you Url.Action, I would assume JsonTest, but is it actually called JsonTestController.cs?

Comment: Your code should work as long as your `GetJsonTest` method is inside `JsonTestController.cs`

Comment: @sleeyuen hi, yes, it is actually called JsonTestController.

Comment: `cshtml` files will be intepreted by the MVC template server. Anything else will not so your js file is tryin to make the literal request to url `'@Url.Action("GetJsonTest", "JsonTest")'`. If you did some debugging in your browser this would be immediately obvious.

Comment: @csharpbd gotcha. i've got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mentioned that you are trying to call `GetJsonTest` from **a javascript file: js**. You have used to generate `ajax url` using

```
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("GetJsonTest", "JsonTest")';
```

above **Razor** statement from `.js` file. The problem is that the `javascript` file can't execute `Razor` statement. But in `.cshtml` can. So, if you use this `Razor` statement from `javascript` within `.cshtml` it will work and if you use this `Razor` statement from `javascript` within `.js` it will not work. You have to call like this from `.js` file:

```
var actionUrl = '/JsonTest/GetJsonTest';
$.getJSON(actionUrl, function (response) {
    if (response != null) {
        $("h2").append("<li>" + response.Id + " " + response.Name + " " + response.Author + "</li>")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you defined route in your routeconfig.cs?

you should have something like

```
   public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "YOUR NAME",
                url: "{YOUR CONTROLLER NAME}/{GetJsonTest}",
                defaults: new { controller = "YOUR CONTROLLER NAME", action = "GetJsonTest" }
            );
    }
    }
```