# ASP.NET Json doesn't appear

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Please refer to this link

http://aspsolution.net/Code/5/5215/How-to-loop-through-ViewBag-List-in-Jquery/#

I followed what is written in the website. However the `Json.Result` doesn't appear. I tried to include this one (`@using Newtonsoft.Json`) in the html but it's still not appearing. Why is that? Is there any solution for this?

This is my script:

```
fillDatatable();

function fillDatatable() {
    var cart = @Html.Raw(Json.Result(@ViewBag.cart));
    alert(cart.Items.ItemID);
}
```

Edited:

```js
if (PurchaseOrder != "") {
    var tableHTML = '';
    $.each(PurchaseOrder, function (index, value) {
        tableHTML += "<tr>";
        tableHTML += "<td>" + value.items.itemID + "</td>";
        tableHTML += "<td>" + value.items.itemModelDescription + "</td>";
        tableHTML += "<td>";
        tableHTML += "<input id='UnitPrice" + value.items.ItemID + "' class='form-control b-r-xl text-right' value='" + value.items.itemUnitPrice + "' oninput='return change_unitprice('" + value.items.itemID + "')' />";
        tableHTML += "</td>";
        tableHTML += "<td>";
        tableHTML += "  </tr>";
    });
    $("#TableRecords").html(tableHTML);
}
```

See my HTML inside the loop where you can see `change_unitprice` function. I'm trying to pass the value of an id there, but according to the result of console it is undefined? Why is that?

Comment: You can refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795997/get-json-from-controller-mvc-in-java-script

Comment: You can refer to here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795997/get-json-from-controller-mvc-in-java-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are referencing does not contain the code you included to the question. It describes how to use `Json.Encode()` to obtain data from the `ViewBag` field. Possible problems why your code doesn't work are:

1. Using not defined the `cart` field.
2. Using the `Items` property that does not defined.
3. Trying to work with HTML document that does not loaded yet.

Therefore, use function from this example as is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var StockList =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.StockList));
        if (StockList != '') {
            var tableHtml;
            $.each(StockList, function( index, value ) {
                tableHtml +="<tr><td>" + value.stockId + "</td><td>" + value.StockName + "</td><td>" + value.StockPrice + "</td></tr>";
              });
            $("#output").html(tableHtml);
        }
    })
</script>
```

If it does not work (probably because of the `jquery` disable by `Layout = null;` line in the *Index.cshtml* ) add the following line after the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

For additional information see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779161/6630084

Comment: It totall worked! But please see my edited comment. Where am I wrong? Is there anything wrong with concatenation ?

Comment: @Jeffrey Estrera: Can you add full code of the `Index.cshtml`, the `Index()` action and your model definition, please?  It seems a bug in code that we don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method that works for complex object would be like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.cart))
```